# Turn warnings into error only within supplied diff

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, compiler-warnings

At a company I used to work at, the build system was set up to turn warnings into errors only within changed code. It worked by supplying generating a diff (typically between the branch you were trying to merge and `master` and then supplying that diff to some compilation tool, and the tool would produce warnings only within the supplied diff.

This was great as it allowed you to e.g. deprecate some function, and have the build system prevent people from introducing new uses of that function, and then remove old usages of that function later.

Unfortunately, I didn't look at the setup closely enough before I left the company, and don't know how to replicate it. My question: How can I replicate this setup?

Question is tagged Clang but I would also be interested in answers that use tooling from other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to implement that, my first idea would be:

1. Get merged file.
2. Analyze diff to figure out which regions were changed.
3. Generate a new file and inject `#pragma` directives<sup>1</sup> that locally enable/disable warnings around the changed regions.
4. Also inject `#line` directives to make it look like warnings/errors are coming from the original file.
5. Compile modified file and save compiler warnings/errors.
6. Delete modified file.
7. Present compiler diagnostics to the user.

---

<sup>1</sup> E.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas for GCC.

Answer (score -1):

Clang supports GCC's [`#pragma diagnostic`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

For example:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"

// ... changed code here ...

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

MSVC also has something similar:

```
#pragma warning(push, 3)
// ... changed code here ...
#pragma warning(pop)
```